# Change class of child on django models

Tags: python, django, inheritance, models

Lets say I have classes in the form:

```
class A(models.Model):
   attrA = models.CharField()
class B(A):
   attrB = models.CharField()
class C(A):
   attrC = models.CharField()
```

And then I create a instnace of B:

```
b = B()
```

Now, based on some decisions I wanted to transform that object b an instance of the C class but with the attrC attribute available. Is that possible?

Comment: What is supposed to be the value of attrC in this transformation?

Comment: That doesn't really matter. I wanted to have access to the attrC on my model instance like it was a instance of C class.

Comment: For polymorphic model you can see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58771595/7405082

Answer (score 2):

In python you can change class of an object like that:

```
b.__class__=C
```

Then all of B's attributes are available even when they are not defined for class C.
Altough b is now instance of the class C it has no C's attributes.
Before saving the object to database (or calling other methods of Model class) you have to add all remaining  attributes of the class C. 
To prove it works I created a simple app. Here are my models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    attrA = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    class Meta:
        abstract=True
class B(A):
    attrB = models.CharField(max_length=128)
class C(A):
    attrC = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

And here are my tests:

```
class ABCTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_changing_classes(self):
        """Changing classes"""
        a = A()
        self.assertIsInstance(a, A)
        a.attrA='bacon'
        self.assertEqual(a.attrA, 'bacon')
        a.__class__=B
        self.assertIsInstance(a, B)
        self.assertEqual(a.attrA, 'bacon')
        a.attrB='spam'
        self.assertEqual(a.attrA, 'bacon')
        self.assertEqual(a.attrB, 'spam')
        a.__class__=C
        self.assertIsInstance(a, C)
        self.assertIsInstance(a, A)
        self.assertNotIsInstance(a, B)
        a.attrC='egg'
        self.assertEqual(a.attrA, 'bacon')
        self.assertEqual(a.attrB, 'spam')
        self.assertEqual(a.attrC, 'egg')
        a.id=None
        a.save()
        self.assertIsNotNone(a.id)
```

Result of the test is OK.

Safer approach is to define method for each class which convert from B to C or from C to B.

Comment: It's not as simple as it seems. That works(although with some possible damages) with regular python python code, not with django.

Comment: Actually I tested it with django 1.6 and it works. After changing class you have all attributes from previous class but none from the new one. You have to add them manually. I am not saying this is the best approach in django just it works.

Comment: did you saved it for, lets say, a mysql database(not sure if it's just mysql, but that's the one i'm using right now)? Cause the problem occurred with me when I was save the model.

Comment: Before saving the object to database you have to add all remaining attributes of its new class.

Comment: Did you do that? Did it go well?

Comment: Thank you, it works! That will be really useful for those that care with design patterns.

Comment: Could you check if when changing from one class to another if the previous object remains on your database? Here It doesn't.

Comment: For this test I used django 1.6, python 2.7 and sqlite3. If I get an object from database, change its class, add new classes attributes and save then I have old record in previous table and new record in the latter. If you change class of object then whatever you do later should not affect table corresponding to the previous class.

Comment: But in case you delete that new object(don't forget that this object references another object by foreignkey. Just like the older object), the delete will cause an error since it will try to delete the parent object that's referenced by someone else in other table.

Comment: If the problem is with referencing other tables and foreign keys then try to change this behavior with on_delete argument when specifying ForeignKey field in model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete

Comment: Actually, the problem is not the ability to delete it or not. But, when I list A, it will still show the object. Just as well when I list B. Right?

Comment: If deleting object which exists in both tables is impossible due to database constraints then once you have saved it it will persist and listing any of classes will show it. Unless you change db behavior or delete all related objects (rows).

Answer (score -3):

b = C() would make the local variable b an instance of the C class. Not sure why you would want to do this though. Can you post more of your code?

Comment: I didn't ask for a instance of the C class. I asked how to TURN the current B class instance into a C class instance, without losing anything. But thanks

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the downvote for trying to help.