# How to convert between models in django-polymorphic?

Tags: django, django-polymorphic

I'm using `django-polymorphic` to model a simple relationship like this:

```py
from django.db import models

from polymorphic.models import PolymorphicModel

class Base(PolymorphicModel):
    attribute_base = models.BooleanField()

class DescendantA(Base):
    attribute_a = models.BooleanField()

class DescendantB(Base):
    attribute_b = models.BooleanField()
```

I would like to find a way to convert an instance of `DescendantA` to an instance of `DescendantB` while keeping the data of its `Base` part (specifically the primary key). In my scenario, related models exist pointing to the instance. I would like to keep these relationships (and the instance's primary key) intact.

Setting the appropriate `__class__` and `polymorphic_ctype` attributes on the instance (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58771595/2487231)) works mostly but predictably results in inconsistent data: The database row for `DescendantA` will not be deleted and continues pointing to the `Base` row.

Is there a clean(er) way to achieve this conversion? I'm inclined to just create a new instance and copy the original data but I hope there's a better way.

---

Related questions:

- [Django multi table inheritance: move instance between child models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48851951/django-multi-table-inheritance-move-instance-between-child-models)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way that works pretty well but uses private parts of Django's API and so might break in the future. I wrote some tests that will alert me if this happens.

The gist of my solution is

- the creation of a new child instance using [`instance.save_base(raw=True)`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/24effbceb871e71d3bc320b91252f743714722df/django/db/models/base.py#L853) which won't save the parent model (and is **not** part of the public API).
- the deletion of the former child instance using [`instance.delete(keep_parents=True)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.delete) which won't delete the parent model.
- setting the correct [`polymorphic_ctype`](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/polymorphic.models.html#polymorphic.models.PolymorphicModel) attribute.

```py
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

# Setup
a = DescendantA.objects.create()

# Create new child instance
b = DescendantB(base_ptr=a)
b.save_base(raw=True)

# Delete the other child instance
a.delete(keep_parents=True)

# Change class and point to correct content type
a.__class__ = DescendantB
a.polymorphic_ctype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(DescendantB)
a.save()
```

---

Related answers:

- [Convert a subclass model instance to another subclass model instance in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51309263/2487231)
- [Django model inheritance: create sub-instance of existing instance (downcast)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30296234/2487231)

Answer (score 0):

So for what I understand by "converting" you really want to persist data that way in your database. Then you do have to create and save a new instance of `DescendantB` copying the data over from your `DescendantA` and then deleting the former as they are two different tables. If they were [proxy models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) though they would share the same table and then all you would have to do would be changing the `polymorphic_ctype`.

What you could try to do is copying over the attributes from the `DescendantA` instance using `__dict__` but that relies of course that both models always share the same fields:

```
from copy import deepcopy

descendant_a = DescendantA.objects.first()  # the one you are copying over
descendant_b_kwargs = deepcopy(descendant_a.__dict__) # creates a dict copying the attributes over from descendant_a
descendant_b_kwargs.pop('_state')
descendant_b_kwargs.pop('base_ptr_id') # remove also the pointer to the parent
descendant_b = DescendantB.objects.create(**descendant_b_kwargs)
descendant_b.delete()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I would like to avoid creating a whole new instance (although this is a good backup plan). Optimally, I would like to create a `DescendantB` row that points to the existing `Base` row and then delete the former `DescendantA` row in an idiomatic way. I hope there are some utilities in `django-polymorphic` that could facilitate this but I couldn't find any.

Comment: Normally in n multi-table inheritance both parent and child are treated as a single entity so it's an odd situation having to change a child pointer (as the child even inherit the primary key from the parent). I doubt `django-polymorphic` would have a native support for such a request, also don't see why such a problem creating a new instance since in the end the ORM will execute the same database operations.

Comment: You could also consider changing your architecture as for what I understand both DescendantA and DescendantB even have the same attributes, using multi-table inheritance would be an overkill. You could consider using proxy models https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#proxy-models.

Comment: Unfortunately, they don't have the same attributes. I just tried to build a minimal example here, sorry for the confusion. The base model has attributes and both descendant models have a separate set of attributes as well. You are completely right that multi-table inheritance (and `django-polymorphic`) would just be a massive overhead otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your first comment. I would like to avoid creating a completely new instance since I'd like to keep the primary key and existing relationships with other models. By creating a new instance, I'd have to replicate both of them manually. I'd rather keep as much information as possible and only replace the necessary parts.