# Django multi table inheritance: move instance between child models

Tags: python, django

Assume I have in `models.py`something like:

```
Class ModelA(models.Model):
    # many fields, including
    relatives = models.ManyToManyField(Person)
)

# also, A is foreign key to other models:
Class SomeOtherModel(models.Model):
    mya = models.ForeignKey(A)

# now we produce two classes with multi-table inheritance
# WITHOUT any additional fileds
Class InhertA1(ModelA):
    pass

Class InhertA2(ModelA):
    pass
```

So as as I understand, this will create Tables for `ModelA`, `InheritA1` and `InheritA1`; each instance of `ModelA` will get a row in the `ModelA`-table only, each instance of `InheritA1` will have  a row both in the `ModelA`-table (basically containing all the data) and another in the `InheritA1`-table (only containing a PK and a OneToOne key pointing to the `ModelA`-table row), etc. Django queries for `ModelA`-objects will give all objects, queries for `InheritA1`-objects only the `InheritA1` ones etc.

So now I have an `InheritA1`-object `a1`, and want to make it into a `InheritA2`-object, without changing the according `ModelA`-object. So previously the parent-IbeToOne Key of `a1` points to the `ModelA`-row with key 3, say (and the `ForeignKey` of some `SomeOtherModel`-object is set to 3). In the end, I want a `InheritA1`-object `a2` pointing to the same, unchanged `ModelA`-row (and the object `a1`removed).

It seems that django doesn't offer any such move-Class-functionality?

### Can I safely implement the according SQL operations myself?

Or will things go horribly wrong? I.e., can I just execute the SQL commands that

1. Create a new row in the `InheritA2`-table, setting the parent-OneToOne key to the one of `a1`,
2. Remove the `a1` row in the `InheritA2`-table?

It seems I cannot do this from non-SQL-django without automatically creating a  `ModelA`-row. Well, for 1., maybe I can create a temporary object `x` that way, then let `p` be the parent of `x`, then change the parent-OneToOne key of `x` to point to the one of `a1`, then delete the obect `p`? But for 2, I do not think that it is possible in non-SQL-django to remove an instance of a child while keeping the parent object?

### Alternatively, is there a good django way to copy instances in django and change references to them?

I.e., I could create a new `InheritA2` object `y`, and copy all the properties of `a1` into the new object, and then go through the database and find all ManyToMany and ForeignKey entries that point to the parent of `a1`
and change it to point to the parent of `y` instead, and then delete `a1`.

That could be done with non-SQL-django, the downside is that it seems wasteful performance-wise (which would be of no great concern for my project), and that it might also not be so "stable" I.e., if I change `ModelA` or other models in relation to it, the code that copies everything might break? (Or is there a good way to do something like

```
Forall models M in my project:
    Forall keys k used in M:
        If k is a descendant of a ManyToMany or Foreign or  ... key:
            If k points to ModelA:
                Forall instances x of M:
                    If x.k=a1:
                        x.k=y
```

The first four lines seem rather dubious.

Remarks:

- Copying without changing the instance can be done in a stable, simple, standard way, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4736172/2010842), but we are still stuck in the same child class (and still have to modify ForeignKeys etc)?
- Changing the class by just declaring it in the standard python way, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967714/change-class-of-child-on-django-models), is not an option for me, as nobody seems to know whether it will  horribly break django.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on changing the children but not the parent, then maybe you could use `OneToOneField` instead of direct inheritance.

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    pass

class InhertA1(models.Model):
    a = models.OneToOneField(ModelA, primary_key=True)

class InhertA2(models.Model):
    a = models.OneToOneField(ModelA, primary_key=True)
```

It gives you the same 3 tables in the database. (One difference is that the pk fields of `InheritA1` and `InheritA2` will be the same id from the parent.)

For changing from `InheritA1` to `InheritA2` you would delete one child instance (this would not affect the parent instance) and then create the other new instance, pointing it to the parent instance.

Well, you can even have a parent instance which has children from both other models, but that would be checked in your view to prevent that.

Let me know if this helps you, even if the answer is a bit late.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the end I gave up on this line of thinking, and just did something similar in the obvious way (I used a single class and a choice field to distinguish between the different kinds).